# Kendo UI Grid and ng-style

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, ng-style

I have a Kendo UI Grid in angular which is reading from my datasource a series of properties.
One of them contains a color string. I want to use said color string to set the background-color for a square-box in the grid.

I'm using the following template for the box:

```
template: "<img class='alarm-box-prediction variable' ng-style={'background-color': dataItem.type}'></img>"
```

The relevant data from my dataSource is the following:

```
dataSource: {
        dataSource: function(data) {
            // Map the stored properties in the data array of objects received to 
            // their corresponding columns in the Grid
            return $.map(data, function(alarmProperty) {
                return {
                    // Change array index to match API once we are getting data from there
                    type: alarmProperty[0],
                    //... there are more properties here but i removed them as they are not the focus
                };
            });
        },
```

The data relevant from the JSON file which is currently serving as my DS (will be changed soon though) is:

```
{
    "alarms": [
        {
            "type": "Yellow",
//...
        }
//...
]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the issue. ng-style needs to be formatted differently because it is being passed as a string to kendo.

```
template: "<img class='alarm-box-prediction variable' ng-style=\"{'background-color':dataItem.type}\"></img>",
```