# How to set style to kendo-grid-column?

Tags: css, angular, kendo-grid

I'm use of `kendo-grid` in my project for many reason.

In one of the cell, I want to set input `TextBox` like:

```
<kendo-grid-column field="value" title="{{l('Value')}}" width="200"></kendo-grid-column>
```

As you see, in client, I have bad style [image: Section of bad style]

Attention that I never use of any `CSS`, which want to effect to this.

Comment: what is ```l('Value')```?

Comment: @fatemefazli: My application is multi-language, "l" is a method that I pass 'value' and set the current language of application.

Comment: can you provide a stackBlitz or fiddle for this issue

Comment: @T.Shashwat what is stackBlitz or fiddle??

Comment: its an online IDE

Comment: if you can provide the rendered html for this 'kendo-grid-column' then we can look to style something using css. Or just provide a demo using codepen  or jsFiddle.

Comment: would be good if you post your full html code.

Comment: @AmirReza-Farahlagha do u use angularjs or angular 2+

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it.

Comment: @T.Shashwat Thanks, I'll try it

Comment: @לבנימלכה Yeah!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set style in kendogrid, you have to override basic css of your selection tag like this:

```
Image processor > a > span > (your general css class)
```

Now you have your css that you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use `ng-style`** (I'm using angular 5 and `[style]` works fo me)

For example:

```
ng-style="{'background-color':'blue'}"
```

Learn here:https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle

```
<kendo-grid-column field="value"  title="{{l('Value')}}" ng-style="{'background-color':'blue'}" width="200"></kendo-grid-column>
```

**EDIT!**

According this answer:[Kendo UI Grid and ng-style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38701510/kendo-ui-grid-and-ng-style)

Use `\"` `\"`:

```
ng-style=\"{'background-color':'blue'}\"
```

Comment: tell me for more help!

Comment: Thanks dud but 'kendo-grid-column' do not support style.

Comment: what about set class and style in css with `ng-class`

Comment: No! not working. is there any way to override kendo CSS??

Comment: do you try the `ng-style`?? tell me if you have error in your console

Comment: Yeah! exactly like your sample that you write. No effective no error in console.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Attribute Style

```
    <kendo-grid-column [style]="{'background-color': '#666','color': '#fff','line-height': '1em'}">
</kendo-grid-column>
```

Comment: Thanks dear kianoush, although style attribute is ok, but inner css relation is better than style attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't like to answer my question, but it's better to answer.

If you want to style to that, you have to find one of `css` class and override that. it's best way to set style to `cell-grid`

GoodLuck.

Answer (score 0):

You can not set style classes in `kendo-grid` but you can find `kendo` classes and override them.